# Not able to find simple-weather project in sonatype repo

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype, sonatype

I have learning Maven by going through [Maven By Example](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/customizing-sect-creating-simple-weather.html). In the 4th chapter its asks to generate a Maven project using archetype plugin ([Find it here](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/customizing-sect-creating-simple-weather.html)). I have been trying to download the project using Mvn archetype:generate and then choosing 16, as they say in the tutorial but no 16 doesnt refer to that project. I know that since more and  more project are added, the position shifts. So I tried searching too but still not able to find it. Has anybody faced the same problem?

```
groupId: org.sonatype.mavenbook.custom
artifactId: simple-weather
version: 1.0
package: org.sonatype.mavenbook.custom
```

Comment: Write an email to sonatype.com?

Comment: Yea I will do that when I am sure I am not doing anything wrong. Thanks

Comment: To be sure you can always search the repository manually at http://search.maven.org/ . Your artifact doesn't seem to be in there.

Comment: Yes I searched here too. Not sure what's the problem. Thanks

Comment: What about this: https://github.com/sonatype/simple-example

Comment: The repo has simple-weather but I think it's incomplete. Something better than nothing. Thanks @khmarbaise

Answer (score 1):

You can clone all the example projects at https://github.com/sonatype/maven-example-en